# NSWindow resizing

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, resize, nswindow

Hello I was wondering if anyone knew of a method or way that you stop the user resizing your window for a Cocoa / Mac OS X application.

If this is not not possible how would you go about resizing the window uniformally.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @JoshCaswell you are right thanks for pointing it out, that question sorted things out, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the min and max sizes to the desired size.

```
CGSize fixedSize = myWindow.frame.size;
[myWindow setMinSize:fixedSize];
[myWindow setMaxSize:fixedSize];
```

Comment: thanks for the help, appreciate it, just trying to get used to all this Xcode and objective c syntax

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, Xcode is an [IDE](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FIntegrated_development_environment&ei=d7uBUOqhMsXHsgas4oGABA&usg=AFQjCNGzsgW3CZUA74q_DmV7NnnkIxNZIw&sig2=QMHp1Z57YAqjvECyoc5xaw), Objective-C is a language and Cocoa is an [API](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FApplication_programming_interface&ei=ibuBUIraLJDbsgbToIGQDg&usg=AFQjCNH_lcIv3goY6Ab6BeZ2HU9NfoE81g&sig2=3nb4bC0zw0SfModIMVibjw).